# TV Station Video Embed Code Keeps Autostarting

Tags: video, embed, jwplayer

I've Googled and searched for a while now on how to get a video embed to stop autoplaying, and I can't seem to get anything to work.

Can anyone help?  Here is the site, the video is down near the bottom of the page.
https://www.prestigek9.com/

This is my code:

```
    <div class="video-wrap">
    <div class="video-embed">
    <iframe width="640" height="360" src="https://media.9news.com/embeds/video/2186497/iframe?autostart=false" allowfullscreen="true" webkitallowfullscreen="true" mozallowfullscreen="true" autoPlay="false"></iframe>
    </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The autoplay attribute should be used with a tag that supports it, for example, a HTNL5 video tag. In your example it is actually being used for the iframe tag.

The iframe tag itself does not support autoplay.

If you look at a YouTube video as an example, you will see the autoplay is actually associated with the video url rather than the iframe tag. It is, in fact for YouTube, just part of the YouTube URL support and not an iframe or a HTML5 video tag attribute - e.g. (classic RickRoll example):

```html
<iframe width="420" height="345" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/oHg5SJYRHA0?autoplay=1" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

For the video to play you need the HTML5 page you are inserting in the iFrame to support an autoplay attribute, or if it is your own HTMNL code in the iframe you need to add the autoplay in the video tag there.

Comment: Hi Mick, I see what you mean.  I wound up getting this taken care of.  Thank you so much for your input on this matter.